# Finding the phase of a complex vector

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-analysis

Let's say we have the complex vector $u=(1−i,2+3i)\in\mathbb C^2$.

How would I find the phase of $u$ ? I know that for a complex vector $z=(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$, its norm is defined by

$$||z||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nz_i\bar{z_i}}$$
But I don't know what is the phase of a complex vector, can anyone assist ? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is not clear for me what phase is either. Could you provide the source of this claim?

Comment: @rushusuixing    This is AC current analysis, because AC is a complex number and also has X and Y directions, so I want to find the overall amplitude and phase, but the phase cannot be found, thanks .